# Multinomial logistic regression with unobserved classes?

Tags: regression, discrete-data, multinomial-logit

Suppose that there are 10 treatments, each of them applied to groups of $n_i=10$ patients (i.e. 100 patients in total). Three types of outcomes are measured on each group, defining categories $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$.

I want to perform [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) on this kind of data, which can be easily done in R using the command `multinom`. However, I did **not** observe category $C_4$ in my data.

**Question** : How can I solve this problem? Do I need to remove category $C_4$?

Comment: Does this mean that $C_3$ was never chosen from the 10 options? Or something else?

Comment: @dimitriy It means that the response can be one of the three $C_i$'s (e.g. healthy, OK, dead). But $C_3$ was not observed, (e.g. no deaths).

Comment: In case this is helpful I find a few hits when I search for "multinomial logistic regression cell count 0", but I don't know if they are directly relevant to your situation.

Comment: I see! I misunderstood what you are trying to do. An ordered logit may make more sense since you have an ordered outcome. But if you never observe dead, that simplifies to an ordinary logit.